# Check if numeric vector contains na or character

Tags: r, rcpp

I have input vectors like:

```
x1 <- c('NA', 'NA', 'NA')
x2 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
```

I want to test (without having a loop), if these vectors contain NA values or character values.

I am trying:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector timesTwo(NumericVector x) {

    if (all(is_na(x)) || (x == NA_STRING))
    {
        Rcout << "NA";
    }

  return x * 2;
}


/*** R
x1 <- c('NA','NA','NA')
x2 <- c(NA,NA,NA)
timesTwo(x1)
timesTwo(x2)
*/
```

but it throws me:

`passing 'const LHS_TYPE {aka const Rcpp::sugar::SingleLogicalResult....discards qualifiers`

I know that the error comes from the fact that I must use x as a string vector and access every single element `x(1) == NA_STRING`.

So, I want to have x as a numericvector but check if it is a character vector, like in R:

`all(is.character(x)`

Comment: In R, an atomic vector can only be of one type. Hence, all its elements are, for instance, characters or none of them. To test that, you would only need `is.character(x)` which returns a length-1 logical vector. You don't need `all(is.character(x))` because there's only one element

Comment: @docendodiscimus The OP wants to return true if there is _either_ a real R `NA` value _or_ there is the text `'NA'`.  Your suggestion won't do that.

Comment: @Tim, yep that's right. I was trying to tell them how it would be in R and that `all(is.character(x))` is not necessary. I cannot comment on how to do it in Rcpp

Comment: I can't comment either :-( ... I checked the docs but nothing ported over for `grepl`.  But, there does appear to be an `is_na` function.

Comment: They're already using that in the example

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this in Rcpp. In C++ there is no uncertainty that `x` is a numeric vector because you define `NumericVector x`. You get an error if your try passing a character vector. You'd probably need to pass a `SEXP` instead, but I don't understand why you don't simply test the type in R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector testNA(const SEXP x) {
  CharacterVector test(1, "other"); 
  if (Rf_isString(x)) test = "character";
  if (Rf_isNumeric(x)) {
    NumericVector y = x;
    if (all(is_na(y))) test = "numeric NAs";
  }

  return test;
}

/*** R
x1 <- c('NA','NA','NA')
  x2 <- c(NA,NA,NA)
  x3 <- list(NA)
  testNA(x1)
  testNA(x2)
  testNA(x3)
  */
```

Output:

```
> x1 <- c('NA','NA','NA')

>   x2 <- c(NA,NA,NA)

>   x3 <- list(NA)

>   testNA(x1)
[1] "character"

>   testNA(x2)
[1] "numeric NAs"

>   testNA(x3)
[1] "other"
```

Note that `x2` is actually not a numeric vector. Those NAs are logical values. You should use `Rf_isLogical` if you want to test for that specifically (or `Rf_isInteger` and `Rf_isReal` for identifying numerics).